# How do I make an ordered rotating status for a discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

I want to make my Discord bot change through statuses in order. For example, I want the bot's status to be "T", then "Te", then "Tes", then "Test", and repeat.

I've made an array ordered in the way I want. This is my current code:

```js
const index = activities_list.sort()
var activitySet = activities_list[index]
client.user.setActivity(activitySet)
```

I'm using Node v12, and discord.js v12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the current index and update it in every `x` seconds. You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for this. Every `x` seconds you update the status and check if this was the last index. If it was, you reset it to `0`, if it was not, increment the index:

```js
const activities = ['t', 'te', 'tes', 'test'];

client.on('ready', () => {
  const updateDelay = 5; // in seconds
  let currentIndex = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    const activity = activities[currentIndex];
    client.user.setActivity(activity);

    // update currentIndex
    // if it's the last one, get back to 0
    currentIndex = currentIndex >= activities.length - 1 
      ? 0
      : currentIndex + 1;
  }, updateDelay * 1000);
});
```