# Discord.Js How I can get bot status with regular order from array, not random?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
const activities = ['t', 'te', 'tes', 'test'];

client.on('ready', () => {
  const updateDelay = 5; // in seconds  
  let currentIndex = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    const activity = activities[currentIndex];
    client.user.setActivity(activity);

    // update currentIndex
    // if it's the last one, get back to 0
    currentIndex = currentIndex >= activities.length - 1 
      ? 0
      : currentIndex + 1;
  }, updateDelay * 1000);
});
```

(This code from Zsolt Meszaros [from an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66028501/6126373))

I tried to use it but it's giving `T T T T T T` as result in Discord.js v13. Not continued like `T TE TES TEST`.

Anyone can help with it? Thanks.

Comment: I've just tested your (or my) code and it works fine in discord.js v13.

Comment: I dont know what happened wrong but it works now... I really didnt understand. Just not fluent with times like 1 2 sec. but it can be about discord limitations. Thank you very much. Also sorry, I didnt know how to mention in here. i wrote your name. its your code :)